# Self-balancing BST supporting in-order-sequential multi-insertions / multi-deletions in logn+klogk time?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, balanced-search-trees, avl-trees, red-black-trees

Given a self-balancing binary search tree of size $n$, I want to perform the following operations:

1. `InsertInOrderSequentialBatch` an ordered sequence of $k$ values (specialized $k \in \{2, 3, 4\}$ or generalized $k \in N $) which are guaranteed to be sequential in an in-order tree traversal immediately after insertion.

   - For example, insert $[310, 320, 330, 340]$ into a balanced tree containing $[100, 200, 500]$.
   - Future insertions might still be between the inserted nodes' values.
2. `DeleteRange` all of $k$ nodes (likewise specialized or generalized) between 2 values in the BST.

For both operations, I want the tree to remain balanced.

With a Red-Black or AVL tree, I can achieve both operations through a sequence of $k$ insertions/deletions in $\mathcal{O}(k \log n)$, but wonder if a data structure (e.g. AVL/RB tree variant) could achieve $\mathcal{O}(\log n + k \log k)$ time for a real-world performance gain (e.g. traverse tree for insertion point, insert balanced tree into insertion point, perform one auto-balance pass)?

My needs are less theoretical and more in terms of wall-time & memory pressure for an implementation of Fortune's Algorithm - an algorithm with high constant-time multipliers is unfortunately not useful. My insertion sequence is biased & frequently multimodal (modes not known prior) with long streaks of insertions/deletions within modes. My tree size is anywhere from 100 to 3000 nodes.

Comment: I've had difficulty finding a name for these operations, let alone papers/slides addressing them. Such pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: (I can see those operations as (search&) splitting and joining BSTs.) (Dang. I should make it a habit to have a peek at existing answers.)

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with `split` and `join` operations, both achievable in $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ for Red-Black and AVL trees.

For Red-Black Trees this is doable either [leveraging finger trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176863/concatenating-red-black-trees/3224033#3224033) or via extending a regular Red-Black Tree as in Ron Wein's ["Efficient Implementation of Red-Black Trees with Split and Catenate Operations"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.109.4875&rep=rep1&type=pdf) implemented in CGAL with criticisms mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029894/red-black-tree-split-concatenate-in-logn-time (Tarjan might have a better paper).

For AVL trees this is doable according to Ramzi Fadel and Kim Vagn Jakobsen's ["Data structures and algorithms in a two-level memory"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.114.4253&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

`InsertInOrderSequentialBatch` is expressable as a split followed by 2 joins. `DeleteRange` is 2 splits followed by 1 join.

Comment: For k=2,3,4, I suspect it is possible to achieve significantly faster performance through a specialized by-cases solution and would greatly appreciate pointers in that direction.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join-based_tree_algorithms

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Set_operations_and_bulk_operations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Set_operations_and_bulk_operations

Answer (score 0):

Red-Black tree insertion requires an amortized O(1) recolorings and rotations; if you know where to insert, doing so and rebalancing is O(1). Therefore multi-insertion can be achieved via a single O(logN) search followed by k amortized O(1) insert-successor-and-rebalance operations, since it is possible to implement insert-successor-and-rebalance such that the new node's Black Height is always <= 2, which bounds the next search to a constant time.

Alternatively, but more complex, if blackHeight(treeN) > blackHeight(treeK), insertion can be done in log(n/k)+k time: treeify k values, then insert the tree k into tree n at a leaf and "pull" it upward to maintain black height invariants. This is very similar to implementing a split-join.

For my personal code, I'm doing the O(logN + k) approach first described if k's tree is smaller in black height than N's. Otherwise, I suspect that past some threshold the split-join approach is going to be faster.